# MYSQL - Select MIN integer in range A - B and is not C?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  `integer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I need to get the smallest integer for a given range (`ex: 1 - 65535`), where data =  'something' and integer != 'number'. (This is just an example, values may change).

There will be cases where:

- Table is empty
- `'number'` might be equal to beginning of range
- `'number'` might be equal to end of range

For example:

IF: `'number'` = 1, `'range'` = '1-254', empty...
RESULT EXPECTED: 2

IF: `'number'` = 2, `'range'` = '1-254'...
    RESULT EXPECTED: 1

IF: `'number'` = 2, `'range'` = '1-254', table has integers: 1,4,6,7,8,9,20
    RESULT EXPECTED: 3

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give us some sample `INSERT` statements? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `integer`
    FROM mytable
    WHERE  data = 'something'
      AND `integer` != 1234
    ORDER BY `integer` ASC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Empty table will give you no rows in the resultset.
Your last test case will give '4'; I don't know where you get '3'.